# English An or A?

Tags: code-golf, string, natural-language, alphabet

Given a string consisting of only upper and lower case letters, output `an` if it begins with a vowel, and `a` if not. For the purposes of this challenge, we'll ignore normal grammar rules, and use a very basic rule instead: if the input begins with a vowel (any of `AEIOUaeiou`), then output `an`. Otherwise, output `a`.

Your program should be case insensitive (`computer` and `CoMpUtER` are the same). This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins

### Test cases

```
airplane: an
water: a
snake: a
hybrid: a
igloo: an
WATER: a
IglOO: an
HoUr: a
unIverSe: an
youTH: a
```

Note that for the last 3, they contradict typical grammar rules, in favour of our simplified rule, and that `y` is not counted as a vowel

Comment: An hour in the Sandbox is far too short. You should wait, as a minimum, 3 days so that plenty of users can see it and offer feedback. I'd suggest adding `hour`, `universe` and `youth` as test cases

Comment: This post came up in the review queues as it has a couple of close votes (closing as "unclear/needs details"). Because of this, I've done some edits to try to clarify the challenge. Feel free to revert anything you dislike/I've gotten wrong

Comment: Can we take input as an array of characters?

Comment: @Shaggy Yes, you can.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129723/discussion-on-question-by-alan-bagel-english-an-or-a).

Comment: `y` at the start of a word always seems to behave like a consonant so `a` is correct in this case.

Comment: [Related](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93264/an-a-or-an-an)

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz In standard English grammar, yes. In this challenge, no: "if the input begins with a vowel (any of `AEIOUaeiou`), then output `an`. Otherwise, output `a`"

Comment: Can I capitalize output?

Comment: @鳴神裁四点一号 Which letters?

Comment: @AlanBreadel lilke `AN` and `A` as long as output is consistent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0 [`-mg`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>9</s> 8 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes input as an array of characters.

```
è\v îÍia
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&flags=LW1n&code=6Fx2IO7NaWE&input=WyJhIiwiYiIsImMiXQ)

```
è\v çÍia     :Implicit map of each element in input array
è            :Count the occurrences of
 \v          :  RegEx /[aeiou]/gi
    ç        :Repeat that many times
     Í       :  "n"
      ia     :Prepend "a"
             :Implicit output of first element
```

The `Í` is Japt's shortcut for `n2<space>` (Mainly intended for converting binary strings to decimal) The space close the `ç` method and the `n` and the `2` are passed to it as individual arguments but as `ç` only expects one argument the `2` is ignored.

Comment: ...but this doesn't even *have* an `n` in it???

Comment: Japt magic, @cairdcoinheringaahing ;) The `Í` is the shortcut for `n2`, which gets passed to the `î` as 2 arguments, which only expects 1 argument. I'll add a full explanation in the morn'.

Comment: @cairdcoinheringaahing, explanation added

Answer (score 13):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 44 bytes

```c
f(int*s){printf("a%.*s",2130466>>*s&1,"n");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzOvRKtYs7qgCMhI01BKVNXTKlbSMTI0NjAxM7Oz0ypWM9RRylPStK79X5afmaKQm5iZp6GpUM2lAAQgDZlFBTmJealAFQowQ2JA6hX09RUS82DKyhNLUotAokCAqQymqjgvMTuVoKqMyqSizBSIMtyqMtNz8vNxmgV3WLhjiGsQQSs903P8/Qkb5pEfCvMkHsNK8zzLUouCCQVZZX5piAdul9X@/5eclpOYXvxftxwA)

#### Commented

```c
f(int *s) {     // *s = input string
  printf(       // print ...
    "a%.*s",    //   the letter 'a' followed by a string with
                //   a dynamic length
    2130466     //   using the bitmask of vowels:
                //     1000001000001000100010
                //     ^     ^     ^   ^   ^
                //     utsrqponmlkjihgfedcba_
    >> *s & 1,  //   output 1 character if the first character
                //   is a vowel, or zero otherwise
                //   (assumes that the shift is modulo 32,
                //   which is guaranteed on Intel and may be
                //   true on ARM as well)
    "n"         //   where the string to be printed is "n"
  );            //
}               //
```

---

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 39 bytes

This version was suggested by [Johan du Toit](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41374/johan-du-toit).

```c
f(*s){write(1,"an",(2130466>>*s&1)+1);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P01Dq1izurwosyRVw1BHKTFPSUfDyNDYwMTMzM5Oq1jNUFPbUNO69n9uYmaehiZXNZcCEKRpKCVmFhUATUhV0rRWKCjKzCsBisXkgXj6@gqJeTBl5YklqUUgUSDAVAZTVZyXmJ1KUFVGZVJRZgpEGW5Vmek5@fk4zYI7LNwxxDWIoJWe6Tn@/oQN88gPhXkSj2GleZ5lqUXBhIKsMr80xAO3y2r//0tOy0lML/6vWw4A)

---

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 36 bytes

This one was suggested by [dingledooper](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/88546/dingledooper).

```c
f(*s){puts(2130466>>*s&1?"an":"a");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P01Dq1izuqC0pFjDyNDYwMTMzM5Oq1jN0F4pMU/JSilRSdO69n9uYmaehiZXNZcCEKRpKCVmFhUAtacCJRX09RUS82AS5YklqUUgUSAAScDEi/MSs1OxiGdUJhVlpkAkkMUz03Py85HUwy0IdwxxDcJikGd6jr8/Ng0e@aEwB6FoKM3zLEstCsb0QmV@aYgHsg21//8lp@Ukphf/1y0HAA)

Answer (score 8):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `english`, 15 bytes

```
[ >lower a/an ]
```

Almost a builtin. For whatever reason, `a/an` doesn't handle capital letters properly so we need to make it lowercase first. Luckily it's simplistic enough that it doesn't return the correct article for 'universe.'

Doesn't work on TIO because the `english` vocabulary postdates build 1525 (the one TIO uses), so have a picture:

[image]

Comment: Interesting that it goes off of the first letter, rather than attempting to mimic the actual grammatical rules about when to use a vs an

Comment: Typo here: *captial*.

Comment: @A.L Fixed, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 37 bytes

```python
lambda x:'a'+'n'*(x[0]in'aeiouAEIOU')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUaHCSj1RXVs9T11LoyLaIDYzTz0xNTO/1NHV0z9UXfN/QVFmXolGmoZSZXpOfr6SpuZ/AA)

-1 thanks to @xnor

Comment: 1 shorter to just do `lambda x:'a'+'n'*(x[0]in'aeiouAEIOU')`.

Comment: @xnor nice! Sometimes i miss the obvious things 

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript, <s>32</s> 31 bytes

*-1 thanks to @Arnauld*

```
s=>/^[aeiou]/i.test(s)?"an":"a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XclBDkAwEAXQvVPIrNoF9hIcREgmDKk0M@KX65e1t30HP4zlCmeq1FbJW9lldH0zjyzB7qkJdRIkBz8QK7XElBdTWJQ62u42RxyuM7IKeV/8CrfukQHBl/kF)

Comment: [31 bytes](https://tio.run/##XclBDkAwEAXQvVPIrNoF9hIcREgmDKk0M@KX65e1t30HP4zlCmeq1FbJW9lldH0zjyzB7qkJdRIkBz8QK7XElBdTWJQ62u42RxyuM7IKeV/8CrfukQHBl/kF)

Answer (score 4):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `r`, <strike>11</strike> 9 bytes

```
hk∨c›‛anẎ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=hk%E2%88%A8c%E2%80%BA%E2%80%9Ban%E1%BA%8E&inputs=test&header=&footer=)

```
hk∨c›‛anẎ
h          - First character of input
 k∨       - All vowels ("aeiouAEIOU")
    c      - A in B? ("h" in "k∨"?)
     ›     - Increment
      `an  - Two-byte string literal "an"
         Ẏ - Slice until B (A[0:B])
```

9 bytes thanks to @Aaron Miller

Comment: Nice one! I messed with some flags and was able to get it down to a pretty jank [10 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=Ṫr&code=%5Ca%3Fhk%E2%88%A8c%5B%5Cn&inputs=test&header=&footer=)

Comment: Make that [9 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=hk%E2%88%A8c%E2%80%BA%E2%80%9Ban%E1%BA%8E&inputs=test&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 4):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 36 bytes

```
1?*(test("^[aeiou]";"i")//"a")//"an"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcSxCsJADADQPZ@RqQpSnB3EQWinQm1xEIWIocYelzZ3p/TnPQff8F5zztv9uogcYoG3C7FouuIOBVdlifTfY84kNjnyDB@KbBA8jQzP5W7yABmcKpwP3bGFenBNA5X2BsnXb7YTw6Kpq746RVEf8sbaHw)

Some longer alternatives:

```
"an"[:match("^[aeiou]?";"i").length+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsJADADQPZ@RSREFVx3EQWinQq04lApRw/X0TGp6p/TnPd97vHNGEmw3L4q3foaXlthr6na4RY/zVWBxsV@su5zJ2xBIGL4U2WAUejL009X8HbwLqnDeN4caSheqCgo9GSQpP2xHhklTU/x0iF5lzEur/w)

```
.[:1]|1?*(inside("aeiouAEIOU")//"a")//"an"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcSxCsIwEADQ/T4jUxW0dHWRDoV2CtQWB3E46VHPhly9NErBbzcOvuE9nintL4fi@imO24x94IEyg8QSy6qxvdnkucH/3qSErLNDT/DGhRSCx4ngvt6UB@DRicC57KoWmtFZC7X0CtE3L9ITwSqxq78yLyw@pJ22Pw)

```
"a"+sub("^([^aeiou](?<x>))?.*";.x//"n";"i")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcHBCoJAEADQ@3zGnNwi/QAj6RDoSTCjQySstOjUsmOzbunPt733fMeIGrc@9Al2ya3Thjjck2K/HJQq0g3m6ZJl6DBHQhWjJpmsdga@ejYC3umXgXHthR5Ag2WG67E9NVANtq6h5ItAcNXHyNnAyqEtfzzNxM7HnTR/)

Answer (score 4):

## Dyalog APL, 21 chars

```
'an'↑⍨1+'aeiou'∊⍨⊃∘⎕c
```

Same logic as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235346) Jelly answer. This answer feels too long...

Comment: [Welcome to Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20861/66833), and nice first answer! Be sure to check out our [Tips for golfing in APL](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/17665/tips-for-golfing-in-apl) page for ways you can golf your program, and be sure to drop by the [APL Orchard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52405/the-apl-orchard) for more APL golfing advice

Answer (score 3):

## [PowerShell Core](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), 33 bytes

```powershell
"a"+"n"*("$args"-match"^[AEIOU]")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7RboJAEEWf2a8gk20DLXxBY4IxJvJEI5g@GNusOAJ2ZenuUmss305Xg23Xxzlz7p1pxAGlKpHzMBcSe7odnXpg8Ag1PHhAmSwUhHum8xJel@NpnCxW4PcdIZFHnMgDVsmGsxohcIHV4AcXemAa5QVdiarZO1qkPK5ltbFQVXAh7KaXcTadW1Jc8CSxpZlY2NfaOv5Emd58dRRtNhs84n/fnYhDNSo9YQoDl@JXg7nGjTty6duT2UlULddmvKdb99c0m@VzOmmVFvtkvTORVWSanLTNc1TqnB6CIX78tZqYkw0VZ@dfnTO/HhqShnWk638A)

Or 36 bytes without regex

```powershell
"a"+"n"*($args[0]-in("AEIOU"|% t*y))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7RasIwFIavm6cIIY7WtbD7IVREsFcdtrILEYn1WLtlSZekc0V99i5Ky5Zdnu98/39OLU@g9BE4jwqpoKOHybkjjDwSQcY@ZarU66dNVAmfTOdJuiKXETbjNgi6K0Kxj7zYJ6xSNWcCSIgJEyQI7/TEDKg7GogW7B0ccmx3qto7qCq5lG7T6zSfLx0pKXmautJCrtxrjUi@QGX/vmplky96DwWX0Rl51IA2M6YhxBS@aygM7PEE0@2z3SnQDTd2fKAHHA@m3axfslmjjfxId282soltk5c1RQFa39J9MILP31Yb8/K@4ub8qfOWw6E@adkVXbsf)

Answer (score 3):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>36</s> 34 bytes

```php
fn($s)=>stripos(_aeiou,$s[0])?an:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSZvs/LU9DpVjT1q64pCizIL9YIz4xNTO/VEelONogVtM@Mc8q8b81F1dqcka@gkqahlJiZlFBTmJeqpKmgp6CUkyekrWCvr5CYh5CRXliSWoRkjQQgFQgFBTnJWan4lOQUZlUlJmCogJVQWZ6Tn4@pglIjgh3DHENwmeHZ3qOvz9eIzzyQ9G8gWZEaZ5nWWpRMJ6gqMwvDfHAtOQ/AA)

Straightforward PHP code. Ignoring accented vowels of course, the `_` is ignored, it is only there so that the index in the string is truthy

EDIT: saved 2 bytes thanks to YetiCGN's suggestions

Comment: Why `strripos` and not `stripos` for -1 byte? With a single character match you need not care about using the first or last occurence of the needle. Also, `à` is two bytes in UTF-8 for one character, you could substitute it for `_` to save 2 bytes.

Comment: @YetiCGN You're right, maybe it comes from my stuttering :D

Comment: `strrrrrrripos!!!` ;-)

Comment: [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62uKQosyC/WCM@MTUzv1RHJbEoPS/aIFbTPjHPKtH6v70dF9f/xMyigpzEvFQrhcQ8rvLEktQiIIurOC8xGyTElVGZVJSZAmJlpufk54NVhTuGuAaBhDzTc/z9wUIe@aFgfaV5nmWpRcEQ0yrzS0M8gKx/@QUlmfl5xf913QA) as a standalone program!

Comment: or also [33 bytes](https://tio.run/##JYzLCsIwEEX3@QoXLhT0B@ojdFFpVgFtcT1iSINhJuSh9OeNTdwdDvdcN7mcj/wUog8ON2vwGnegDKW2E3LccsAGDpmfGctgvLOAqlkBsg9E5RdiAeFVFJvmhzfPQkZborq6t0N3LUpoK2VVPY21Syjeyt/@bzOloV/oSy4awpD3lx8) doing it another crazy way!

Comment: @640KB nice use of `strspn`! didn't even know this function, it actually can be very useful!

Comment: @640KB do you want to post your own answer or do I integrate your improvements?

Comment: Do what you like with it! It's just a small spin on yours anyway!

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript, <s>91</s> 73 bytes

-18 from @emanresuA

```
a=(s)=>{return 'a'+('AEIOU'.includes(s.charAt(0).toUpperCase())?"n":"");}
```

### Explanation

```
a=                        declares variable
(s)=>{                    ES6 Arrow Function
return 'a'+               return statement
('AEIOU'.includes(        check if in string 'AEIOU'
s.charAt(0)               first letter of string
.toUpperCase())           case insensitivity
?                         ternary operator
"n"                       if true, add 'n'  (an)
:"");                     else, add nothing (a)
}                         finish function
```

[Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##XcmxCsIwEADQ3a8IWXKHmDqKpUpQB6eCUJyPNGglJCFJ6yB@e8RFoW99D5oo6TiEvJo2pVADCZvdK5o8RscEiSUIdTq3nZCD03bsTYIk9Z2iyrBGmX0XgokHSgYQ99zxLedYv4v2LnlrpPU3IBDX9nIUiDVjVcVoMVv16@@6edPTx/7f5QM)

[Old TIO link](https://tio.run/##XcmxCsIwEADQ3a8IWS6HmjqKUqWog1NBKA7icKRBKyEpSVoH8dtjXRQ6vOk9qKegfNPGeb9MyejIKBcB883L69h5y4BgKi5QwAwOg@OgHFRwlY1Vpqt1EEGqO/kiigXK6Kq21X5HQQvELbd8xTmu30k5G5zR0ribIAHn8rQHxDVjWcZoMtri19@146an8/W/0wc)

first time here so let me know if I missed something

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and nice first answer! A couple of golfing tips: - Strings have a `includes` method, so you can go `'AEIOU'.includes(`; `s` doesn't need to be in  parentheses, and you don't need the `let` at the start.

Comment: @emanresuA so we don't have to do it in 'strict mode' (`'use strict';`)

Comment: No, you don't. See our [Tips for golfing in Javascript](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/2682/tips-for-golfing-in-javascript) page for more tips to make your code shorter.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes

```
ḢeØc‘⁾anḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjkWph2ckP2qY8ahxX2Lewx2L/z/cveXQ1oc7Fz9qmGsFlD7crhn5/39iZlFBTmJeqpVCYh5XeWJJahGQxVWcl5gNEuLKqEwqykwBsTLTc/LzwarCHUNcg0BCnuk5/v5gIY/8ULC@0jzPstSiYIhplfmlIR5AFgA)

The footer simply extracts the test case from the `:` separated string

### How it works

```
ḢeØc‘⁾anḣ - Main link. Takes a string S on the left
Ḣ          - Extract the first character of S
  Øc       - Yield vowels; "AEIOUaeiou"
 e         - Is the first character in that string? Yield 1 if so, else 0
    ‘      - Increment, yielding 2 for vowel-starting strings, 1 otherwise
      ⁾anḣ - Take that many characters of the string ⁾an
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, <s>28</s> 20 bytes

*27 bytes for the actual code; +1 byte for -E to get **say***

*-8 bytes by golfing further*

```perl
$_=/^[aeiou]/i?an:a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/18l3lY/LjoxNTO/NFY/0z4xzyrx/3/P9Bz//H/5BSWZ@XnF/3ULAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/) `--continue-on-error`, 25 bytes

```bash
>$1:l
s=n<[aeiou]*
<<<a$s
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724qjhjwRobG3U9dTu9ZD0gb2lpSZquxU47FUOrHK5i2zyb6MTUzPzSWC0uGxubRJViiPzNCD2utPwiBUMFjcTUovyCnMS8VIXQvMyy1KLizJJKhcj80pIMhYrKnPyCjPy8VE0FoMkKurrJ-XklmXmlqbr5ebqpRUVAAyCWKqgYKqipKRTlKmhBzF-wAEIDAA)

When `[aeiou]*` fails to match (i.e., the word begins with a consonant), Zsh would normally exit with a "fatal" error. The aptly named option `CONTINUE_ON_ERROR` overrides this, and simply skips the assignment line `s=n` instead.

Answer (score 2):

## TI-Basic, 43 bytes

```
Input Str1
"a
If inString("AEIOUaeiou",sub(Str1,1,1
"an
```

Ouput is stored in `Ans`.

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 47 bytes

```r
function(s)"if"(grepl("^[aeiou]",s,T),"an","a")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc2xCsIwEAbg3aeQc0kgTyA4OAjtVNCIgyicmsTQcClJo/TpY6VDshx89/Pfhax3WSd6jtYTixysBmaCGhyD@xWV9ekGIgrJBSDBPIBnzQBtGBySAr7ZrpFW8@qLowqL/4yEvSp8T49gX8XWOO@r9mUvD8cSt8Z1XRU3/lzdTtR@VDjV3yefZLM4/wA)

Other solutions:

```r
function(s)c("a","an")[1+grepl("^[aeiou]",s,T)]   # 47 bytes
function(s)paste0("a","n"[grepl("^[aeiou]",s,T)]) # 49 bytes
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Nim](https://nim-lang.org), 61 bytes

```
proc a(i:string):string=
 if i[0]in "aeiouAEIOU":"an"else:"a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Lc7BCoMwDAbge58iZCATdthZGMyDoDAQNmUH8dC5qGGulVY3fHpX6sghX0J@iOL3uo5GNyD3HNnJsOrCfz8J4Ba4OtasACWxnuMky0uMUCqkwZIDrjsoyE6i1QYsuMtzJdw1m3GQivDghq@cyHhZJV/brl8ehp@e3A1ae93jIrl6Zd0lz71SXW7ZWWUfMrctvui5SFFAHQmgptfufRtCAOgqALv@AA)

Simple explanation + ungolfed code:

```
# Define function
proc a(i: string): string =
 # If the first character of 'i' is in "aeiouAEIOU",
 # Then it is a "an"
 if i[0] in "aeiouAEIOU":
  return "an"
 # Else, return "a"
 else:
  return "a"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 39 bytes

```java
s->s.matches("(?i)^[aeiou].*")?"an":"a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY5Ba8JAEIXv/ophQUhEl/aqreKhRQ9FqJYexMIY17i62Q27symh@NunMebiYXjMzDfvzRkrHJ0PF9ZF6TzBuellJG3kMdqMtLNyMOllBkOAD9QW/noAZdwbnUEgpEYqpw9QNLtkTV7bfLsD9HlIWxTgvfN5uW@Hd5kCrvzcwiu0EIfRNMgCKTupkIhkptOfLSrt4k4ORDoTaMVYoOBJix@dh6RCD6QCjR/iAG5zr0I01Li3KRLL0tTJDU4nHbWuA6lCukiybB6iYyL6z09hDP3Qt2LYOg87n@7o2rvVlRm1Lw1axb9IynOweFF8qvdeH1jnxjn@nm/ePnmZm9WKF@7Lc7TLSvm14trFzeIf)

Answer (score 2):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <del>80</del> <del>76</del> <del>74</del> <del>64</del> <del>40</del> 35 bytes

*-24 thanks to @Franky*
*-5 thanks to @ovs*

```hs
a(x:_)='a':['n'|elem x"aeiouAEIOU"]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY/BasMwEETv@YplibENoR9gcCCHQEwLLo1DD6UUtd3YIvJKSHIjQ//dddyeivY0zPCYnU64Cyk1yd5o66Gh4O8erWR/nkQWire8TEVavKScfpOiHgIKknrY7av6hK@TgQAjlGAGf/T2gWENZqEBE1cABUMfXnILiduAJTcoP0vIEpfjgmYCQg6ZPP@pspxN3xED1vcIpBwBXq3mFvNVLyTfygCFtEYJJpwlI2y3K/i9ObsKT/YW/PMdiwtF/G58t/IzEshWaR1reN41@6cIULWqrmPAQZ9iHw1cfZE9RleMemgOCzP9AA)

Comment: `Data.Char.toLower` has 17 bytes minimum. Expanding `"aeiou"` to `"aeiouAEIOU`" just costs 5 bytes. Using that and guards instead of `if` gets me down to 39 bytes

Comment: pattern matching (`a(x:_)|elem x"...`) and `1>0` instead of `True` both save a byte. Using a list comprehension to conditionally append a `n` saves a few more bytes: [TIO](https://tio.run/##bY/BasMwEETv@YplibENoR9gcCCHQEwLLo1DD6UUtd3YIvJKSHIjQ//dddyeivY0zPCYnU64Cyk1yd5o66Gh4O8erWR/nkQWire8TEVavKScfpOiHgIKknrY7av6hK@TgQAjlGAGf/T2gWENZqEBE1cABUMfXnILiduAJTcoP0vIEpfjgmYCQg6ZPP@pspxN3xED1vcIpBwBXq3mFvNVLyTfygCFtEYJJpwlI2y3K/i9ObsKT/YW/PMdiwtF/G58t/IzEshWaR1reN41@6cIULWqrmPAQZ9iHw1cfZE9RleMemgOCzP9AA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>12</s> 11 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
„anžMIнlå>∍
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//UcO8xLyj@3w9L@zNObzU7lFH7///pXmeZalFwakA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKS/f9HDfMS847u8628sDfn8FK7Rx29/3X@RyslZhYV5CTmpSrpKJUnlqQWAenivMRsED@jMqkoMwXIyEzPyc8H0uGOIa5BQNozPcffH0h75IeC1JfmeZalFgWDtFTml4Z4KMUCAA).

**Explanation:**

```python
„an          # Push "an"
   žM        # Push builtin constant "aeiou"
     I       # Push the input-string
      н      # Pop and leave just its first character
       l     # Convert it to lowercase
        å    # Check if this lowercase first letter is in the vowels-string
         >   # Increase it by 1
          ∍  # Shorten the "an" to this length
             # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 2):

## F#, 61 bytes

```fs
let a(i:string)=if"aeiouAEIOU".Contains(i.[0])then"an"else"a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc6xCsIwEIDh3acIB0Iz2DoLDkWEdipoi4M4nHhtD@OlJKnSp4/uZv744e/95mXFxmgoKMx454NjGfSee0BiO5fHuukgP1gJyOIzzq/bmw4jCaAAGU@AEItCteTDavrFoRcFaw8qQwXIbjIoBPrfPhjIpcALPpPFuNwdP1LCg7E2BZeyPZ5SUA@maVJQ2S55NUv9JndOji12bivQ8Qs)

Alternative 66 bytes solution:

```fs
let a(i:string)=if"aeiouAEIOU".Contains(i.Chars(0))then"an"else"a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bc4xC8IwEIbh3V8RDoRmsHUWHEoptFNBW5xPvLaH8VKSVOmvj@5mfvg@3tEfXlZsjIaCwoxPPjiWSZ95BCS2a1m33QB5ZSUgi884r2Z0PjtqHWYSQAEyngAhFoXqyYfd8nsIoyjYe1AZKkB2i0Eh0P/2wUAuBV7wmVzM293xIyU8GWtTcCv7@pKCdjJdl4LGDsmqVdo3uWsybLNr34COXw)

Check if the input's first character is in `aeiouAEIOU` or not (`if"aeiouAEIOU".Contains(i.Chars(0))`), if true, return "an" (`then"an"`), else, return "a" (`else"a"`)

Ungolfed version:

```fs
let anOrA (inpt : string) =
 if "aeiouAEIOU".Contains(inpt.Chars(0)) then "an" else "a"
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vim](https://www.vim.org), 20 bytes

```
lD:s/[aeiou]\c/an
ra
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/v/P8fFqlg/OjE1M780NiZZPzGPqyjx//@S1OISAA)

Explanation:

```
lD                 # Keep only the first character
  :s/[aeiou]\c/an  # Replace any of AEIOUaeiou with 'an'
ra                 # Replace the first character with 'a'
```

Answer (score 2):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 34 bytes

```
f(*s){puts("a\00an"+('A\04D'>>*s&2));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNzknMS///P01Dq1izuqC0pFhDKZEhMU9JW0PdkcVF3c5Oq1jNSFPTuvZ/bmJmnoYmVzWXAhCkAZVlFhUANacqaVor6OsrJObBJMoTS1KLQKJAAJKAiRfnJWanYhHPqEwqykyBSCCLZ6bn5OcjqYdbEO4Y4hqExSDP9Bx/f2waPPJDYQ5C0VCa51mWWhSM6YXK/NIQD2Qbav//S07LSUwv/q9bDgA)

Partial based on [dingledooper's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235350).

`\00` and `\04` should be replaced by raw bytes instead of using escaped character sequences.

Answer (score 2):

### Python, <s>42</s> 37 bytes

```python
lambda s:'a'+'n'*(2130466>>s[0]%32&1)
```

Uses the same logic as [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/235350/103498) C answer, but I have to take `%32` because python bit shifts aren't modulo 32.

Note that I take advantage of order of operations by using `%32` and `&1` (which is `%2`) to avoid needing parentheses.

(-5): Removed the `ord()` by taking a bytestring (`bytes`) instead of a `str`.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 37 bytes

```js
s=>'a'+(/[aeiou]/i.test(s[0])?"n":"")
```

Answer (score 2):

## [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), 33 bytes

```
(match("^[aeiou]";"i")|"an")//"a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyr8/18jN7EkOUNDKS46MTUzvzRWyVopU0mzRikxT0lTX18pUen/f6XEzKKCnMS8VCUupfLEktQiIF2cl5gN4mdUJhVlpgAZmek5@flAOtwxxDUISHum5/j7A2mP/FCQ@tI8z7LUomCQlsr80hAPJQA)

Answer (score 2):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CLC-INTERCAL), 144 bytes.

In ISO-8859-1:

```
DO,1<-#99DOWRITEIN,1DO;1<-#2DO;1SUB#1<-#52DO;1SUB#2<-#360(1)DO.1<-',1SUB#3'~#31(3)DO¬x(6)DO¬x(7)DO¬x(24)DO¬xDO;1SUB#2<-#0DOCOMEFROM.1DOREADOUT;1
```

### Usage

- Stdin and stdout, both of each as a line.

  - No trailing LF for output.

### [Copy and paste the following Bash script to test online on shinh's server!](http://golf.shinh.org/check.rb)

```bash
printf %s "$(cat<<'x'
DO,1<-#99DOWRITEIN,1DO;1<-#2DO;1SUB#1<-#52DO;1SUB#2<-#360(1)DO.1<-',1SUB#3'~#31(3)DO¬x(6)DO¬x(7)DO¬x(24)DO¬xDO;1SUB#2<-#0DOCOMEFROM.1DOREADOUT;1
x
)" | iconv -f UTF-8 -t LATIN1 >x.i
wc -c x.i
sick x.i
while IFS=: read x _; do
echo $x
./x.io <<<$x
echo
done<<'x'
airplane: an
water: a
snake: a
hybrid: a
igloo: an
WATER: a
IglOO: an
HoUr: a
unIverSe: an
youTH: a
x
```

### How it works

The idea was just to make "an" on the variable `;1` and then erase "n" unless vowel. I used Baudot character set for input.

Answer (score 2):

## [International Phonetic Esoteric Language](https://github.com/bigyihsuan/International-Phonetic-Esoteric-Language), 40 bytes

```forth
0h"aeiouAEIOU"dʔdpʌɔ|a|"an"ɔ|e||a|"a"|e|
```

Expects a string, leaves the string and a `"a"` or `"an"`.

#### Ungolfed:

```forth
               (s -- a/an)
0h             (first char)
"aeiouAEIOU"dʔ (is c a vowel?)
dp             (discard vowels)
ʌɔ|a|          (if c is not a vowel, go to |a|)
|an|"an"ɔ|end| (when c is a vowel)
|a|"a"         (when c is not a vowel)
|end|
```

Answer (score 2):

## [GAIA](https://github.com/Glan9/Gaia), 32 bytes

```
{(⟨₵v&!!⟩⟨₵V&!!⟩v}⟨“a”p⟩⟨“an”p⟩?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/#gaia)

Probably could be shortened, especially on the second section.

Explanation:

```
( -takes first letter of the input

₵v& - is member (&) of string aeiou (₵v) -> returns the contained letter if member, empty if not.

₵V& - is member (&) of string AEIOU (₵V) -> returns the contained letter if member, empty if not.

!! - if the passed value is empty returns 0, otherwise 1

v - is logical or

{(⟨₵v&!!⟩⟨₵V&!!⟩v} - so this checks if the first letter is member of either lower or upper case vowels

⟨“a”p⟩⟨“an”p⟩? - this checks for the value passed by the first section, if true executes the first member, if false the second.

p -prints a string
```

Answer (score 2):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 21 bytes

**Solution:**

```
{$`an`a@^"aeiou"?*_x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNS8/7/z/NqlolITEvIdEhTikxNTO/VMleK76i9n@auoZSYmZRQU5iXqqStVJ5YklqEZAuzkvMBvEzKpOKMlOAjMz0nPx8IB3uGOIaBKQ903P8/YG0R34oSH1pnmdZalEwSEtlfmmIh5LmfwA)

**Explanation:**

```
{                   } / function taking implicit x argument
                  _x  / convert x to lowercase
                 *    / take first
         "aeiou"?     / find right in left
        ^             / null?
  `an`a@              / index into 2-item list (`a;`an)
 $                    / convert to string
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-pl`, 19 bytes

```perl
$_=a.n x/^[aeiou]/i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcExDoJQDADQvadwcBUmRwcHEphIFOJgxNTYYGPT/hQ@yuWt7yVy2Uds7wcsdPMthysSW76VHIHsSVAJPjiTw6T4JnitD@cn8ChmcDl21QmaUdoWausdsjYL@ZlgtdzVP0szm06xk/QH)

---

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) + `-lpF/^([aeiou]).*$/i`, 11 bytes

Using `-F` and the resulting `$#F` can save a bunch of bytes.

```perl
$_=a.n x$#F
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxCsJADADQPV8heIMKtpOjg4OlnQptxUFUIoY2eCRH2lP7857vBTK/S8nd95jJ4uuWRUrIFjwKwQcnMhgFXwTD/DB@AvdeFc6H7thA1fu6hlJPBlGqN1lLMGvsyp@GiVXGtPWhyG@rCxJrvK6zjcv5Dw)

Comment: Do the standard golfing rules allow treating code as a flag? You should be adding the flags to your score anyway.

Comment: @CJDennis https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/92901

Comment: @Dingus That answers one part of my comment. But what if I create a hypothetical language that can take a full program as a flag for a 0 byte program? Does every golfing challenge then become a 0 byte solution in my hypothetical language?

Comment: To be honest, I do enjoy exploring what useful flags you can use on Perl answers, but I am aware that this one is particularly cheeky. It's entirely possible to have the whole program be passed in via `-F` but does go against the spirit. When using Perl to parse files, `-F` is a standard feature I use a lot so I like to share what can be done, though it does often get me negative attention.

Comment: I think this is extra contentious now with one of the golfing langs having some flags that help it a lot, so it might garner more negative attention than these ones do. I have however considered it too, like, another Perl flag that would wrap the code in `for(/./g){...;;print}`, or similar. I don't think anything is stopping you from doing that, technically. But it might not earn points... It's a valid discussion though for sure. I guess the process is open a meta discussion if you think it needs clarification.

Comment: @CJDennis What you describe has actually [been done before](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/205249/92901). My interpretation is that the point about ‘cheating flags’ covers this kind of approach: yes you can do it, but it probably won’t win you any favour. All 0-byte answers in the ‘flag language’ are equivalent so there’s no possible competition.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 35 bytes

```
"aeiou">ir'aL' *+s<l~s<'al['nf!]p&o
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/18pMTUzv1TJLrNIPdFHXUFLu9gmp67YRj0xJ1o9L00xtkAt////9Irk1Jyc1LwSAA)

Takes advantage of the constraints on the input, meaning we can assume it's only upper or lower case letters....

```
"aeiou"                             - Push codepoints for the vowels on the stack
       >i                           - Switch to clean stack, read input
         r                          - Reverse stack (first char/codepoint to top)
          'aL                       - Is it uppercase?
             ' *                    - Push "32" and multiple w/ test results
                +                   - Add to the codepoint (maps it to lowercase)
                 s<                 - Save the resulting codepoint, switch stacks
                   l~               - Load the char/codepoint, search on stack
                     s<             - Save boolean result, switch to clean stack
                       'a           - Push "a" on the stack
                         l[  f!]p   - if/then "true" if a vowel
                           'n       - Push "n" on the stack
                                 &o - Print the stack
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 39 bytes

```
{if(it[0]in "AEIOUaeiou")"an" else "a"}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VcuxCsJADIDhWZ8iZEoGwbmg4ODg5FCcxCFDqsEzJ22uS@mznxUnt58P/meOZF5HSSANUBu9@Z03@1/Ark7WkcV1ezMHPBxP54uo5YKM4giaBgUUnGtXHF5iTgzTevVe7khOQljcRu0HReY/f@TQ9MW5fgA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 13 bytes

```
a¿№aeiou↧§Ｓ⁰n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S85ILErOT8z5/z@gKDOvREMpUUnTmiszTUHDOb8UzE/NzC9V0lHwyS9PLUpOLE7VcCzxzEtJrdDwzCsoLQkuAWpL19DUUTDQBAIFqCl5QFP@/6/MLy3J@K9blgMA) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
a
```

Always output an `a`.

```
¿№aeiou↧§Ｓ⁰
```

If the lowercased first letter of the input can be found in the string `aeiou`, then ...

```
n
```

... output an `n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), 23 bytes

```
i`([aeiou])?\w+
a$#1$*n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/M0EjOjE1M780VtM@plybK1FF2VBFK@///8TMooKcxLxUrvLEktQiruK8xOxUrozKpKLMFK7M9Jz8fK5wxxDXIC7P9Bx/fy6P/NAirtI8z7LUouBUrsr80hAPAA) Link includes test cases. Explanation: The first letter of the word is case-insensitively checked for a vowel and the word replaced with `a` plus an `n` if the first letter was a vowel.

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 89 bytes

Typical Lexurgy pattern: Match some text, place  a marker, delete everything past and including the marker.

```
a:
*=>an|/$ _ {a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U}
else:
*=>a|/$ _
b propagate:
[]=>*/| _
c:
|=>*
```

### Alternative, 52 bytes

```
a:
*=>a\ /$ _
n:
\ =>n\ /$ a _ {a,e,i,o,u,A,E,I,O,U}
```

Returns the input string with `a`  or `an`  prepended.

Answer (score 1):

## [Go](https://go.dev), <s>102</s> 96 bytes

```go
import."regexp"
func f(s[]byte)string{l:="a";if a,_:=Match("(?i)^[aeiou]",s);a{l+="n"};return l}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LZDBSsNAEIbPyVMsA4Usxp6lIYoHoT1IRSseYq3TupsuTXfDZlINoU_iJQg-RB_Fuw9i1s1pvvkP__zzf37lpjuVuNlhLtgelQ7VvjSWGMg9wXdN8vzi59VrY7AiFx8lhLLWGyajKluuGxK8Iqt03haTFBASJRnGq0l6i7TZRhBdKf6SoVCmXkJc8QTb4iwFDcfECqqtZsVxuPP77-tSRJy1YUCioopNUpYt_QknBoDKlgVqAbHb3pGE9Vhp3A3qtllb9eZZ5YUxHp-uFzf3Hmd5MZ97nJrHwaHWs4OwD4NJY-rF1OExDKSxbBWTS2NR92X5cC5Q39T4ro9HMoLRgaWXbHR41hAzivuSfEcRcc6d0fBr1_n5Bw)

Regex matching for beginning vowel, case insensitive.

- -6 by @The Thonnu

Comment: [96 bytes](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LZDBSsNAEIbPyVMsA4Usxp6lIYoHoT1IRSseYq3TupsuTXfDZlINoU_iJQg-RB_Fuw9i1s1pvvkP__zzf37lpjuVuNlhLtgelQ7VvjSWGMg9wXdN8vzi59VrY7AiFx8lhLLWGyajKluuGxK8Iqt03haTFBASJRnGq0l6i7TZRhBdKf6SoVCmXkJc8QTb4iwFDcfECqqtZsVxuPP77-tSRJy1YUCioopNUpYt_QknBoDKlgVqAbHb3pGE9Vhp3A3qtllb9eZZ5YUxHp-uFzf3Hmd5MZ97nJrHwaHWs4OwD4NJY-rF1OExDKSxbBWTS2NR92X5cC5Q39T4ro9HMoLRgaWXbHR41hAzivuSfEcRcc6d0fBr1_n5Bw)

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 9 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
ü╟(sGö╥"▼
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=81c728734794d2221f&i=airplane%0Awater%0Asnake%0Ahybrid%0Aigloo%0AWATER%0AIglOO%0AHoUr%0AunIverSe%0AyouTH&a=1&m=2)

#### Approach

1. Get first character of input
2. Is it a consonant? Result is an integer
3. Right-trim that many characters from `"an"`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 22 bytes

```
@O`AEIOUaeiou`vK=u13*q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Kygtzqj8/9/BP8HR1dM/NDE1M780oczbttTQWKvw////Sq5lqUWVSfkplQo5@WWpxQoBIA1KAA)

I think this one is quite slick!

```
                         \ Input is on the INPUT stack
@                        \ Reverse the input (so first letter is on top of stack)
 O                       \ Go to the OUTPUT stack
  `AEIOUaeiou`           \ Push all vowels
              v          \ Bring the first letter to this stack
               K=        \ Pop and check equality in place, replacing each vowel with
                         \ 0 or 1 accordingly.
                 u       \ Remove duplicates from the stack and sort ascendingly.
                         \        If first letter was a vowel: we now have [0,1]
                         \        Otherwise: we have [0].
                  13*    \ Multiply all stack elements by 13.
                         \        If first letter was a vowel: we now have [0,13]
                         \        Otherwise: we have [0].
                     q   \ Interpret the stack as lowercase alphabet, indexing mod 26.
                         \ Print the result.
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 45 bytes

```scala
s=>if(s.matches("(?i)^[aeiou].*"))"an"else"a"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XYtBCsIwFET3OcUnq8RFD1BIxQO4ElelhW/9qZE0LfmpINKzx0h3zmKG4c3wgB7zfHvSkOCMLsBHANzJwlSKwjhyDacY8d1eUnRh7HQN1@ASmLIUL/Rg652YZk8wmU3jrOJqwjQ8iJVUR6f7FsnNa1cdpNYSgyTPJFFmKBI/W8o9@aCskuji4jFQmf4jXsPokZl4h5vYRP4C)

Answer (score 1):

## [Lua](https://www.lua.org/), 44 bytes

```lua
print((...):find'^[aieouAEIOU]'and'an'or'a')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yylN/P@/oCgzr0RDQ09PT9MqLTMvRT0uOjEzNb/U0dXTPzRWPREokpinnl@knqiu@f//f8/0HH9/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Logically](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Logically), <s>373</s> <s>358</s> 348 Bytes

```
@e:2i:o:b;XOR(2i)(b)NOT(b)(o)
@E:4a,4b:o:4t;AND(4t)(o)e(a0,b0)(t0)e(a1,b1)(t1)e(a2,b2)(t2)e(a3,b3)(t3)
@A:4i,4a,4b,4c,4d,4e:o:5t;OR(5t)(o)E(4i,4a)(t0)E(4i,4b)(t1)E(4i,4c)(t2)E(4i,4d)(t3)E(4i,4e)(t4)
@M b:8t,_,j,k;WRITE(h,h,l,l,l,l,h,h,l)()READ(h)(_,8t)A(t4,t3,t2,t1,l,l,l,l,l,l,h,l,l,h,l,l,l,h,h,h,h,l,h)(j)AND(j,t0)(k)WRITE(k,l,h,h,h,l,h,h,l)()
```

### Ungolfed

```
@Equals
i: 4a, 4b;
o: o;
b: 4t;
AND(4t)(o)
XOR(a0,b0,1)(t0)
XOR(a1,b1,1)(t1)
XOR(a2,b2,1)(t2)
XOR(a3,b3,1)(t3)

@EqualsAny
i: 4i, 4a,4b,4c,4d,4e
o: o;
b: 5t;
OR(5t)(o)
Equals(4i,4a)(t0)
Equals(4i,4b)(t1)
Equals(4i,4c)(t2)
Equals(4i,4d)(t3)
Equals(4i,4e)(t4)

@Main
b:8t,_,j,k;
WRITE(h,h,l,l,l,l,h,h,l)()
READ(h)(_,8t)
EqualsAny(t4,t3,t2,t1,
        l,l,l,l,
        l,l,h,l,
        l,h,l,l,
        l,h,h,h,
        h,l,h,l)(j)
AND(j,t0)(k)
WRITE(k,l,h,h,h,l,h,h,l)()
```

First, Writes an `'a'` to STDOUT. Simultaniously it reads a byte from STDIN.

The byte is then tested as a vowel by first confirming:

- The 2^1 through 2^4 bits are one of the following: `0000`, `0100`, `0010`, `1110`, `0101`, which is checked via a big "EqualsAny" gate.
- The 2^0 bit is high through a seperate And gate
- The 2^5 bit is ignored, as that controls for case.
- Bits 2^6 and Bits 2^7 are ignores as we are garunteed a letter

When the result is pulled high, an `'n'` is sent to STDOUT. Otherwise, the chip terminates.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṃh⁺`anɱ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSU4M2glRTIlODElQkElNjBhbiVDOSVCMSZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PWFpcnBsYW5lJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMGFuJTBBd2F0ZXIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwYSUwQXNuYWtlJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMGElMEFoeWJyaWQlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwYSUwQWlnbG9vJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMGFuJTBBV0FURVIlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwYSUwQUlnbE9PJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwJTIwLSUzRSUyMGFuJTBBSG9VciUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMC0lM0UlMjBhJTBBdW5JdmVyU2UlMjAlMjAtJTNFJTIwYW4lMEF5b3VUSCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMCUyMC0lM0UlMjBhJmZsYWdzPUM=)

##### Explanation

```python
ṃh⁺`anɱ  # Implicit input
ṃh       # Is the first letter a vowel?
  ⁺      # Increment (0|1) -> (1|2)
   `anɱ  # Take the first characters from "an"
         # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 54 [bits<sup>v1</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 6.75 bytes

```
hA›‛anẎ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=1#WyJ+PSIsIiIsImhB4oC64oCbYW7huo4iLCIiLCIhKFxcdyspOiAoLiopXG5haXJwbGFuZTogYW5cbndhdGVyOiBhXG5zbmFrZTogYVxuaHlicmlkOiBhXG5pZ2xvbzogYW5cbldBVEVSOiBhXG5JZ2xPTzogYW5cbkhvVXI6IGFcbnVuSXZlclNlOiBhblxueW91VEg6IGEiXQ==)

Independently discovered.

### Explained

```
hA›‛anẎ­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎⁪⁪⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁣​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁤⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁢⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
hA       # ‎⁡Is the first letter a vowel?
  ›      # ‎⁢Increment the boolean
   ‛anẎ  # ‎⁣And get "an"[0:that]
```

Created with the help of [Luminespire](https://vyxal.github.io/Luminespire).

Answer (score 0):

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://uilebheist.srht.site/), 126 bytes, CAPITAL OUTPUT

```
(1000)DO$@1SUB#1<-#3DO$@1SUB#2<-#12(1)DO.1<-2@1SUB#3(3)DO¬x(6)DO¬x(7)DO¬x(24)DO¬xDO$@1SUB#2<-#0DOCOMEFROM.1~#31DOFINISHLECTURE
```

### Usage

Now `1@1` (which is usually `$@1`) is *tail* output; one of `A` or `AN` shall be written. `2@1` is tail input.

### Example

```
DOSTUDY#1AT(1000)INCLASS@1
DOENSLAVE@1TO,1
DOENROL,9TOLEARN#1
DO,9<-#2   DONOTE output
DO,1<-#99  DONOTE input
DOCOMEFROM#99
(33)DOWRITEIN,1
DO,9LEARNS#1
(99)DOREADOUT,9
DONEXTFROM#33
DO.1<-,1SUB#1
DORESUME'.1~.1'~#1

(1000)DO$@1SUB#1<-#3
DO$@1SUB#2<-#12
(1)DO.1<-2@1SUB#3
(3)DO¬x(6)DO¬x(7)DO¬x(24)DO¬x
DO$@1SUB#2<-#0
DOCOMEFROM.1~#31
DOFINISHLECTURE
```

## [CLC-INTERCAL](https://uilebheist.srht.site/), 131 bytes

First ever [lecture](https://uilebheist.srht.site/docs/lectures.html) answer.
Lecturified [user100411's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/237598/113493)

```
(1000)DO$@1SUB#1<-#52DO$@1SUB#2<-#360(1)DO.1<-'$$@1SUB#3'~#31(3)DO¬x(6)DO¬x(7)DO¬x(24)DO¬xDO$@1SUB#2<-#0DOCOMEFROM.1DOFINISHLECTURE
```

### Usage

`$@1` is hybrid output to have a string of either "a" or "an" which must be predimensioned. `$$@1` is tail input to have English word.

### How it works

Using [Baudot code](https://uilebheist.srht.site/docs/charset.html#baudot) for input.

```
(1000)DO$@1SUB#1<-#52
DO$@1SUB#2<-#360              DONOTE $@1 is "an"
(1)DO.1<-'$$@1SUB#3'~#31      DONOTE these five labels represent vowels
(3)DO¬x(6)DO¬x(7)DO¬x(24)DO¬x DONOTE 
DO$@1SUB#2<-#0                DONOTE $@1 is "a"
DOCOMEFROM.1                  DONOTE come from those five labels
DOFINISHLECTURE
```

### Example

```
~ $ cat > a.i
DOSTUDY#1AT(1000)INCLASS@1
DOENSLAVE;1TO,1
DOENROL;1TOLEARN#1
DO;1<-#2
DO,1<-#99
DO,2<-#1
DOCOMEFROM#99
(33)DOWRITEIN,1
DO;1LEARNS#1
(99)DOREADOUT;1+,2
DONEXTFROM#33
DO.1<-,1SUB#1
DORESUME'.1~.1'~#1

(1000)DO$@1SUB#1<-#52
DO$@1SUB#2<-#360
(1)DO.1<-'$$@1SUB#3'~#31
(3)DO¬x(6)DO¬x(7)DO¬x(24)DO¬x
DO$@1SUB#2<-#0
DOCOMEFROM.1
DOFINISHLECTURE
~ $ sick -lRun a.i
Ant
an
ant
an
bat
a
Bat
a
E
an
e
an
i
an
I
an
o
an
O
an
u
an
U
an
P
a
Q
a
[EOF actually]
*621 Pointless RESUME
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Uiua](https://www.uiua.org), 25 bytes

```
("a"|"an")∊:"aeiouAEIOU"⊢
```

[Test pad](https://uiua.org/pad?src=0_8_0__RiDihpAgKCJhInwiYW4iKeKIijoiYWVpb3VBRUlPVSLiiqIKClt7ImFpcnBsYW5lIiAiYW4ifQogeyJ3YXRlciIgImEifQogeyJzbmFrZSIgImEifQogeyJoeWJyaWQiICJhIn0KIHsiaWdsb28iICJhbiJ9CiB7IldBVEVSIiAiYSJ9CiB7IklnbE9PIiAiYW4ifQogeyJIb1VyIiAiYSJ9CiB7InVuSXZlclNlIiAiYW4ifQogeyJ5b3VUSCIgImEifV0KCuKJoSjiipTiiY3iipRGwrDiip8pCg==)